# Get a returned value from a simple setInterval function

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

Why is it that if I have a function that returns a value it shows in the console each time I call the function but if I place the same function in `setInterval` it quits returning the value. I.E.:

```
function run() {
    return 'Hello world';
}

a = setInterval(run, 1000); //'Hello world' is not shown in the console every second

//Calling run() returns 'Hello world' to the console
run(); //'Hello world'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `setInterval` is to execute a function every X milliseconds. In your original code, when the `run` function returns each time, its returning to the context of the native `setInterval` function. The `setInterval` function does NOT console.log it out for you automatically.

When you run your code `run();`, it returns the value `Hello world`. The only reason you see its value displayed on screen is because the console evaluates the expression and returns its value for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

instead of return Hello World, you should console.log("Hello World") if that is the effect you want.  Your script is being interpreted as you expect. It is running a function that returns "Hello World" every second. But that returned string is not being logged to the console until you include that piece of functionality.

```
function run() {
  console.log("Hello world");
  return 'Hello world';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your target is not console as output stream in your code but when you invoke the run() from console it simply returns the string to console, may try callback:

```
var run = function(fn){
    fn("hello world");//invoke the callback function
};

setTimeout(function(){
  run(alert);//target output to alert
  run(console.log);//now its console
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Liam is correct. This is what is a bit confusing:

`Calling run() returns 'Hello world' to the console` is ***not*** what is happening. Calling `run()` returns "Hello world" to the ***caller of the function***.

If you are in the console, and enter an expression, the value of the expression is output to the console. If you enter `1+1` you will get `2`. If you enter `Math.sqrt(25)` you will get `5`. So if you enter `run()` you will get `Hello world`.